# Why does my Tic Tac Toe Deep Q-Learning implementation not learn to block opponent moves?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to solve Tic Tac Toe with a Deep Q-Network.

The Environment:

An array of length 9 is used to represent the state of the game where 1 stands for the current player's marked positions and -1 for the next player's. 0 is used for non marked positions. A variable **turn** is used to decide whose turn is next. An action is represented as a list with row and column number. 0 Reward is given for non terminating moves and draws. A win is given a reward of 1.

Example:

```
 x | - | -

 - | - | o 

 - | - | -
```

is represented as [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0], here x is represented as 1 and o as -1 as next turn is x's
an action [1,2] will change the state to

```
 x | - | -

 - | - | o 

 - | x | -
```

represented as [-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0], here x is represented as -1 and o as 1 as next turn is o's

Deep Q-Network:

The q function takes in a state and an action to output the q value associated with that move for that state
I update the q function by using the target q value for state s and action a as

> target q value(s,a) = gamma*(reward(s,a) - q value(s',a'))

Where gamma=1, s' is the next state after the move a is done at state s and a' is the next optimal move for the next player decided by the q function.

I am subtracting the q value from the reward as per my understanding of minimax algorithm.

The best action is obtained by using the action from a list of legal moves to get the q values for the current state and the action with the highest q value is considered the best move

I am using an online q-network to provide the next optimal move which is updated during every sample and an offline q-network which provides the q value for obtaining the target q value which is updated less frequently as per DDQN implementation.Along with epsilon decay exploration and exploitation.

I am also using an experience replay buffer

Neural Network used is

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(50, input_dim=11, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

with rmsprop optimizer with learning rate .01

epsilon=1 to .05 with decay rate of .9995

experience replay buffer size = 500 episodes

batch_size for training = 500 states and actions

the offline model is updated with the weights of the online in an interval of 500 episodes.

After training for 20000 episodes the loss was fluctuating [loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJSIu.png)

The DQN failed to block moves and was only interested in completing a row. I want to understand what went wrong in this implementation. Is it because DQN is unstable or any flaws I have made .Any help is appreciated. It is my first time posting and I am not familiar with how to write a question, please correct mistakes in the question.

[This is the code but it is not well written](https://github.com/gokulav137/TicTacToe/blob/master/Tic_Tac_Toe.py)

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could also post the plot of rewards vs timesteps.

One of the things you could try is by backpropagating the discounted rewards through each episode. In essence, after each episode is terminated, you should make the rewards to be:

`new_reward = gamma^(T-t)*terminal_reward`

You store these rewards in the replay buffer instead of the zero-rewards you will be getting from the environment. This would alleviate the problem of sparse rewards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By back propagating the reward do you mean using Td lambda? I see how that will solve the sparse reward problem. Thank you I will try to do that. I don't understand what plot you mean by rewards vs timesteps. Is it the reward (0 for draw and 1 for win) vs the episode no.

Comment: Yes, I meant TD-lambda. Generally, to check if an RL algorithm has converged or not, we test the algorithm on the environment for one episode after every n-timesteps of training. So we plot this episode reward while testing vs the time steps. Hope this explanation helps.